# Is "erzähl's" the short form of "erzählen es"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-request

I just came across a sentence in my textbook: "Ich erzähl's dir gleich."
As I looked up in the dictionary, there is no such a word as "erzähl's". So I guessed maybe it's the short form of "erzählen es". But I'm not sure.
Also, I saw a sentence "Echt? Erzähl." in the script of a conversation. Is this also the short from of something?

Comment: This should be two separate questions

Comment: In the song "Röslein auf der Heiden", there a line "sah's mit viellen Freuden". `sah's` is the abbreviation of `sah es`. `erzähl's` seems the same.

Answer (score 2):

"erzähl's" is indeed short for "erzähle es".

"Echt?" The "Echt?" is equivalent to a surprised "Really?!"

The "Erzähl!" is also short for "Erzähle es". So if you want to know something from a person you say one of those: "Erzähl's mir!" ; "Erzähl!" ; "Erzähle es mir!".

"Erzähle es mir" would be the most "formal" out of the 3.

Comment: "Erzähl!" is the normal regular imperative of the verb "erzählen" and no short form.

Comment: I am pretty sure it's both. But you have got a point there.

Answer (score 1):

"Ich **erzähl's** dir gleich." is short for "ich **erzähle es** dir gleich".

"Echt? Erzähl." is very abbreviated colloquial speech, short for something like: "Ist das echt [=wahr]? Erzähle es mir"

Comment: There are many colloquialisms like that. "Ich sach ma" is very common for "Ich sage einmal". "Sozagn" is very common für "sozusagen". "Buntsreblik" is what you often hear when politicians mean "Bundesrepublik".

Comment: "Buntsreblik" is not a colloquialism, it's just sloppy enunciation

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. May I ask one more thing about the grammar? I know that most sentences follow the pattern [subj] [verb][indirect obj][direct obj]. In this case, is it ok to say "ich erzähle dir es gleich?" ?

Comment: @Dennis if there are two pronouns the direct object comes first

Comment: @PiedPiper - How would you exactly differentiate between colloquialism and sloppyness?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I don't claim you can differentiate exactly. There is a large overlap. But some things fall more obviously into one of the two groups, like the example above. Of course that's just my opinion

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I think this is a good definition of colloquailism: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colloquialism "Colloquial language consists mostly of contractions or other informal words and phrases known to most native speakers of the language"